# 4 state 'progress' bar react component

Tags: reactjs, progress-bar

I need a component that will look like this and depending on state something should change. (The point is to show progress of an page. for example 1- choose food, 2-choose drink, 3-choose payment method)
It feels like someone should have shared similar component somewhere, in the past but I cannot find the right name for my google question. Can someone help me with the right name for it or possibly give link to stackoverflow question about similar component?

[image]

Comment: Is this a good example of what you're looking for? https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/#stepper

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this https://bit.dev/primefaces/primereact/steps from https://bit.dev.

There should be also a lot of other useful components